# How to select DISTINCT entries in SQLite Flutter with whereArgs?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, distinct

I want to return Distinct records from a table in SQLITE flutter by giving some condition such as return All the distinct records where ID = x (where x will be taken by the user).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the [SQFlite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) you can use a `query` or a `rawQuery` to perform that, in both cases you need to pass the `where arguments` as an `array`, and for the `distinct operator` you can do it as follows:

```
  /// [GET] Get all the data by date using a query
  getData(String date) async {
    final db = await database;
    final response = await db.query(
      "TableExample",
      distinct: true,
      orderBy: 'id',
      where: 'date = ?',
      whereArgs: [date],
    );
    //...
  }

  /// [GET] Get all the data by date using a rawQuery
  getDailyPollResponsesPerRangeDate(String date) async {
    final db = await database;
    final response = await db.rawQuery(
      "SELECT DISTINCT TableExample.id, TableExample.date "
      "FROM TableExample "
      "WHERE TableExample.date == ? "
      "ORDER BY TableExample.date DESC",
      [date],
    );
    //...
  }
```